# Load texture from Blender object .obj to Ursina Engine

Tags: python, ursina

Problems with Blender .obj files. If anyone knows how to solve the problem, please tell me.

I am trying to load the texture from Blender in Ursina Engine but I dont know how. Anyone knows how to separate the texture and the object in an .obj file?

Answer (score 0):

When you export a Blender object, an .mtl file should also be Exported Automatically. But, there isn't a way to directly apply mtl textures in Ursina yet. You could try saving the texture as a PNG file in the Blender, UV Editor Menu.